# Getting number of days within a week which belong to the same month only using JS

Tags: angularjs, date

I want to find out number of days belonging to a particular week which is in the same month only. For an example if I provide week number and month then The system should provide the total number of days that belong to the given week but also to the same month. week 1 in 2019 contain 7 days from 30th of December to 5th of January. Therefore total number of days in the week 1 of January is 5 days. I use the following code to get the starting and ending of a week

```
 Date.prototype.getWeekRange = function() {
  var date = new Date(this.getTime());
  date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  // Thursday in current week decides the year.
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 3 - (date.getDay() + 6) % 7);
  // January 4 is always in week 1.
  var week1 = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 4);
  // Adjust to Thursday in week 1 and count number of weeks from date to week1.
  return 1 + Math.round(((date.getTime() - week1.getTime()) / 86400000 - 3 + (week1.getDay() + 6) % 7) / 7);
}

function getDateRangeOfWeek(weekNo, y){
    var d1, numOfdaysPastSinceLastMonday, rangeIsFrom, rangeIsTo;
  var tmpRangeArry = [];
    d1 = new Date(''+y+'');
    numOfdaysPastSinceLastMonday = d1.getDay() - 1;
    d1.setDate(d1.getDate() - numOfdaysPastSinceLastMonday);
    d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + (7 * (weekNo - d1.getWeekRange())));
    rangeIsFrom = (d1.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d1.getDate() + "-" + d1.getFullYear();
    d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + 6);
    rangeIsTo = (d1.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d1.getDate() + "-" + d1.getFullYear() ;
    tmpRangeArry.push(rangeIsFrom);
    tmpRangeArry.push(rangeIsTo);
    return tmpRangeArry;
};
```

But I can't figure out how to remove days of different month from the week days

Answer (score 0):

This is a minimal verifiable complete algorithm for what you're trying to achieve... the week starts from Monday in this code.

- for week=5 & month=1... we get answer: **4** (for Jan 28 - Jan 31)
- for week=5 & month=2... we get answer: **3** (for Feb 01 - Feb 03)

working **snippet** below:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.myWeek = 1;
  $scope.myMonth = 1;
  $scope.weekStartDate;
  $scope.weekEndDate;
  $scope.numberOfDaysFromThisMonth = 0;

  $scope.getDateRangeOfWeek = function(w, m, y) {
    $scope.numberOfDaysFromThisMonth = 0;
    var d = (1 + (w - 1) * 7); // 1st of January + 7 days for each week
    $scope.weekStartDate = new Date(2019, 0, d);
    $scope.weekEndDate = new Date(2019, $scope.weekStartDate.getMonth(), $scope.weekStartDate.getDate() + 6);

    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      let newDate = new Date(2019, $scope.weekStartDate.getMonth(), $scope.weekStartDate.getDate() + i - 1);
      if ($scope.myMonth && newDate.getMonth() + 1 == m) {
        $scope.numberOfDaysFromThisMonth = $scope.numberOfDaysFromThisMonth + 1;
      }
    }
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Enter the Week of the year in question: <input type="number" ng-model="myWeek"><br/> 
  Enter the Month for which you need the count of days: <input type="number" ng-model="myMonth"><br>
  <br/>
  <button type='button' ng-click="getDateRangeOfWeek(myWeek,myMonth, myYear)"> get date </button>
  <br/><br/>
  <b>Start of week</b>: {{ weekStartDate }} <br/>
  <b>End of week</b>: {{ weekEndDate }} <br/> <br/> # of days for Month:{{ myMonth }} in Week:{{myWeek }} is: <mark>{{ numberOfDaysFromThisMonth }}</mark>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to input weekNumber and Year

Comment: in this case... for fifth week of 2019... what will be the answer? 4 (for Jan) or 3 (for Feb) ?

Comment: Where can I define the year? the two input fields are just month and week number